# LNK2005: already defined error

Tags: c++

I am working on a school assignment, and I get this strange error (I am quite new to C++).

I should find the first value between 1500 and 1900. When I build it the first time, everything is ok, but when I build it the next time, I get this error:

```
error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900(int)" (?greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900@@YA_NH@Z) already defined in Lab5.obj
```

If I then change the code slightly (change the type in the predicate function to double) it builds again one time.

```
template<typename T>
T MyStlClass<T>::myFindIf(list<T> &theList) {

    list<T>::iterator it = find_if(theList.begin(), theList.end(), greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900);
    return *it;
}

bool greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900(int value){
    return (value >= 1500 && value <= 1900);
}
```

I have read on this site that it is because that I include the ".cpp" file, but on the other hand, I have also read, that I need to include the ".cpp" file, when I am using templates.

Comment: Please post more code, it seems that you're adding a header file which already defines the `bool greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900(int){ }`function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also read, that I need to include the ".cpp" file, when I am using templates.

Throw away/downvote/identify for us the resource that told you to do that.

There is a good reason that it did so, but the recommendation was wrong and it has led you *directly* to this issue.

**Never `#include` a `.cpp`.**

The file you put template definitions in should be called something like `.ipp` rather than `.cpp`, so that then your IDE does not confuse it with a "regular" source file and build it with the rest of your project. Such a file is then, like a `.h`, *only* `#include`d.

Comment: +1, We need a bigger typeface for that. (and "bonfire" comes to mind regarding such nonsense resources).

Comment: I would much rather provide the definition in the header than provide yet another separate file that needs to be included by either the header or the final user...

Comment: @David: Yeah, or that. I don't think I've ever actually used an `.ipp` file (well, there was _one_ occasion, when it was quite a big class template), but I'm comfortable recommending it for the general case. If nothing else, it gets across the point of _not including `.cpp`_ more powerfully than saying "just don't include anything".

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how should the file hierarchy then be? What file should be included where?

Answer (score 0):

Your `greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900` is *not* a template, that's why it's wrong to `#include` its body multiple times (and that's why it *must* be linked exactly once).

You have to split out this function from the templated stuff. This function should be in a cpp file never `#include`d by anything, but added to your project. (It seems that you already have its *declaration* where it's called -- it should remain so).

As of the templates, you *may* heed another answer's advice (renaming to `*.ipp` which you will `#include`, removing from project), but the error will disappear before you do (compiling additional template-only source file to an empty object is useless, but it does not hurt).

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an header-only library/module, then use `#pragma once` to avoid multiple inclusions, and mark the `greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900` function `inline`:

```
// MyStlClass.hpp

#prgma once

....

template<typename T>
T MyStlClass<T>::myFindIf(list<T> &theList) {

    list<T>::iterator it = find_if(theList.begin(), theList.end(), greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900);
    return *it;
}

// NOTE inline here:
inline bool greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900(int value){
    return (value >= 1500 && value <= 1900);
}
```

Comment: Or just don't put `greaterThan1500SmallerThan1900` in an included file.

Comment: @Lightness: Maybe he would like the convenience of a header-only reusable module/library.

Comment: Yeah this function seems really useful for a library

Comment: @Lightness: you must have a useful crystall ball.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Oh you have no idea! :)